# Display code snippet with Javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, code-snippets

I want to be able to print a code snippet with script-tags using JavaScript.

This is more or less what I want to print:

```
<script src='URL type='text/javascript'></script><script>functionName();</script>
```

I tried:

```
jQuery('selector').text("<pre><script src='URL type='text/javascript'></script><script>functionName();</script></pre>");
```

Comment: I can think of various reasons that *might* fail, but only under certain conditions. It appears to be perfectly workable code. What's the problem? What happens? What doesn't happen? What messages are displayed in the console of your developer tools?

Comment: You want `$('selector').append($("<pre>", {text: "<script>…"}));`

Answer (score 0):

Use some syntax higlighter for that (ex https://highlightjs.org/).

```html
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>test</title>
    <!-- load highlight.js css & js -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.0.0/styles/default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.0.0/highlight.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- set up your tag which want to highlight -->
    <pre><code class="xml"> 
&lt;script src='URL type='text/javascript'>&lt;/script>&lt;script>functionName();&lt;/script>
    </code></pre>

    <script>
    // initialize highlight
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```